# Root account wont work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am logged in as root in my MySQL database. I try to run the following commands:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'
    ->   IDENTIFIED BY '[password]'
    ->   WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
mysql>
```

I get the following error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Im assuming my root user isnt set up correctly. Any ideas?

Edit

```
mysql> show grants for root
    -> ;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*738393F115A47ACE272D98F4719B8491A2B8296F' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sometable`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                               |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `Test`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what does `show grants for root@%` reveal? That account would need the `grant` option to be able to configure other users. mysql's default root account is `root@localhost`, so if you're logging in via tcp, you could be on a "different" root.

Comment: @Marc B Ive added it, see edit. Ive logged on via ssh.

Comment: You don't have a general grant option. You can only grant privs on the `sometable` and `test` databases, not to `*.*`

Comment: @Marc B How can I get a grant option?

Comment: You'd have to log in to the real root account. Most likely `root@localhost` has full rights+grant privs on `*.*`. doing `mysql -p -u root` at the shell on the mysql server SHOULD log in via local unix socket rather than a tcp one.

Comment: If you get totally stuck you can install the "MySQL Workbench" program and use that to edit your root priviledges and sometimes that method can help you get going in cases where your not understanding the command line.

Comment: @djangofan Thanks, ill give the MySQL Workbench a look

Answer (score 3):

You might be logged into the database with an account named root, but the account you are in as does not have the correct privileges.

```
mysql> select user();
```

And follow that up with a:

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user\G
```

Look for the user and host columns to match exactly as the output. Look for **grant_priv** and it needs to say **Y**. More than likely there is additional root accounts without the grant_priv.

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 Host: localhost
                 User: root
             Password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          Select_priv: Y
          Insert_priv: Y
          Update_priv: Y
          Delete_priv: Y
          Create_priv: Y
            Drop_priv: Y
          Reload_priv: Y
        Shutdown_priv: Y
         Process_priv: Y
            File_priv: Y
           Grant_priv: Y
      References_priv: Y
           Index_priv: Y
           Alter_priv: Y
         Show_db_priv: Y
           Super_priv: Y
Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
     Lock_tables_priv: Y
         Execute_priv: Y
      Repl_slave_priv: Y
     Repl_client_priv: Y
     Create_view_priv: Y
       Show_view_priv: Y
  Create_routine_priv: Y
   Alter_routine_priv: Y
     Create_user_priv: Y
           Event_priv: Y
         Trigger_priv: Y
             ssl_type: 
           ssl_cipher: 
          x509_issuer: 
         x509_subject: 
        max_questions: 0
          max_updates: 0
      max_connections: 0
 max_user_connections: 0
```

Comment: When I enter the `select * from mysql.user\G` command, I get : `ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'
ERROR:
No query specified
`

Answer (score 0):

> When I enter the select * from mysql.user\G command, I get : ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user' ERROR: No query specified

This means you're not logged in as `'root'@'%'`.  You're logged in as 'root'@'localhost', which are two different users.  If you run `SELECT USER();` as mentioned above, it will likely show you `'root'@'localhost'.`

If you are logged in as `'root'@'localhost'`, you are logging in via local socket.  Logging in through a TCP connection will get you access as `'root'@'%'`, which will then give you access to change grants based on the output you listed initially.  To do so, login with:

`mysql -u $user -p $pass -h 127.0.0.1`